# How to make PHP Calculator Store and Display History

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP and my entire PHP Calculator is finished, except I need to make so that the latest 5 calculations I made need to be stored in a div called "Logs". I know I have to work in **_SESSIONS** but I have no idea where to start and how to set this up. I'm sure this is a pretty basic thing to create for many people out there but I have no idea how to set it up.

There are two things to keep in mind. There is a **Reset Button** that should **destroy the SESSION**, so these past calculations don't have to be stored forever. They need to disappear after the user has closed their browser or if they have pressed the Reset button.

Any help would be so much appreciated!

**Form HTML code:**

```
<div class="calculator">
        <form action="Index.php" method="POST">
            <ul>
                <!-- First number -->
                <li>
                    <label for="numberOne"><strong>Number one:</strong></label>
                    <input class="inputNumbers" type="number" name="numberOne" placeholder="Enter a number">
                </li>

                <!-- Operation -->
                <li>
                    <label for="operation"><strong>Operation:</strong></label>
                    <select class="inputNumbers" name="operation" id="operator-list">
                        <option value="+">+</option>
                        <option value="-">-</option>
                        <option value="x">x</option>
                        <option value="/">/</option>
                        <option value="sqrt">^</option>
                        <option value="pow">√</option>
                    </select>
                </li>

                <!-- Second number -->
                <li id="second-input">
                    <label for="numberTwo"><strong>Number two:</strong></label>
                    <input class="inputNumbers" type="number" name="numberTwo" placeholder="Enter a number">
                </li>

                <!-- Decimal Slider -->
                <li>
                    <label><strong>Decimal: </strong><span id="value_slider"></span></label>
                    <input type="range" name="slidebar" min="0" max="10" value="0" id="slider" class="slider_style input">
                </li>

                <!-- Calculate & Reset button -->
                <li>
                    <input class="btn-calculate" type="submit" name="btnCalculate" value="Calculate">
                    <button class="btn-reset" type="reset" name="resetForm" onclick="btnReset()">Reset</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Logs -->
    <div class="logs-container">
        <div class="logs-title">Logs</div>
            <div class="logs">
                <!-- LOG LATEST 5 CALCULATIONS -->
            </div>
    </div>
```

**Calculation.PHP code:**

```
$Result = 0;

if (isset ($_POST['btnCalculate']) ) {

$numberOne = $_POST['numberOne'];
$operation = $_POST['operation'];
$numberTwo = $_POST['numberTwo'];

if ($operation == '+') {
    $Result = ((int)$numberOne + (int)$numberTwo);
}

else if ($operation == '-') {
    $Result = ((int)$numberOne - (int)$numberTwo);
} 

else if ($operation == 'x') {
    $Result = ((int)$numberOne * (int)$numberTwo);
}

else if ($operation == '/') {
    if ($numberOne and $numberTwo > 0)
    {
        $Result = $numberOne / $numberTwo;
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Cannot divide by 0');</script>";
    }
}
   
else if ($operation == 'sqrt') {
    $Result = sqrt($numberOne);
}

else if ($operation == 'pow') {
    if ($numberOne and $numberTwo > 0)
    {
        $Result = pow($numberOne, $numberTwo);
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter a number in both fields');</script>";
    }
}

else $Result = 'Unknown';
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I defined the variables at the top of my page with session_start and defined inputs and operator

And then I tried putting this to echo the answers:
<?php echo $_SESSION['numberOne'], $_SESSION['operation'], $_SESSION['numberTwo']; ?>

Comment: I think in your case, which is server-side calculator form, using $_GET values would be better than a session. You could link to particular computations with $_GET and you wouldn't need to store anything on your side.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me. But F.Igor has answered my question. It works exactly how I wanted it to be ❤

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you've been helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), first of all you may start any PHP script using $_SESSION with [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
<?php

session_start();
```

Then you can initialize an array result storage with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['results'])){
  $_SESSION["results"] = [];
}
```

And add stored values using :

```
$_SESSION["results"][]="New result";
```

For example, you can store the operation result after calculation, like here:

```
if ($operation == '+') {
    $Result = ((int)$numberOne + (int)$numberTwo);
    $_SESSION["results"][]="$numberOne + $numberTwo = $Result";
}
```

You may use any string/number/array values to store the result in a more structured way if you want. Then you can add your saved results to the HTML form page (must be a `.php` file, not `.html`), for example:

```
<div class="logs">
    <?php echo implode("<br>",$_SESSION["results"]); ?>
</div>
```

To clean/reset the results array, you can add a new 'reset' operation or something like this to do that:

```
if ($operation == 'reset'){
    $_SESSION["results"] = [];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is exactly what I wanted. I have one more question, how do I destroy the session when I click on my Reset button and resets the logs div?

Comment: I've added code for reset. You must implement a call to the PHP script to fire this action in the `btnReset()` function.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. I tried a lot of things but it doesn't seem to reset the logs

Comment: I made a typo and used `$_SESSION["result"]` instead of `$_SESSION["results"]` please check again using the correct variable name

Comment: I already figured out the typo. I just don't know how to set this up, I think I'm just very stupid. But it's still a learning process for me. I don't know what I need to do in my Reset.js file because that's where the btnReset() method is called from. I don't know how to reset it when the Reset button is pressed :|